# IdentityServer4 client for Password Flow not including TestUser claims in access token

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid

I'm trying to create a sandbox application, using the (legacy) Resource Owner Password flow in IdentityServer4. I've set up a brand new ASP.NET Core 3 project with these packages:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4" Version="3.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation" Version="3.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
```

I'm using the following startup sections:

```csharp
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(new[] { new ApiResource("foo-api") })
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(new[]
    {
        new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
        new IdentityResources.Profile(),
        new IdentityResources.Email(),
        new IdentityResource("role", new[] { JwtClaimTypes.Role }),
    })
```

```csharp
    .AddInMemoryClients(new[]
    {
        new Client
        {
            // Don't use RPO if you can prevent it. We use it here
            // because it's the easiest way to demo with users.
            ClientId = "legacy-rpo",
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
            AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = false,
            RequireClientSecret = false,
            AllowedScopes = { "foo-api", "openid", "profile", "email", "role" },

        },
    })
```

```csharp
    .AddTestUsers(new List<TestUser>
    {
        new TestUser
        {
            SubjectId = "ABC-123",
            Username = "john",
            Password = "secret",
            Claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "user"),
                new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, "john@example.org"),
                new Claim("x-domain", "foo") },
        },
    })
```

And then I serve a static `index.html` file that calls the `/connect/token` endpoint like this:

```javascript
const response = await fetch("/connect/token", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: new URLSearchParams({
        "grant_type": "password",
        "client_id": "legacy-rpo",
        "username": "john",
        "password": "secret",
        // scope omitted should net *all* scopes in IDS4
    }),
});
```

But it returns me an access_token that (decoded) looks like this:

```json
{
  "nbf": 1588582642,
  "exp": 1588586242,
  "iss": "https://localhost:5001",
  "aud": "foo-api",
  "client_id": "legacy-rpo",
  "sub": "ABC-123",
  "auth_time": 1588582642,
  "idp": "local",
  "scope": [
    "email",
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "role",
    "foo-api"
  ],
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ]
}
```

**I'm missing e-mail, role, etc. as top-level entries in the `access_token`.**

When digging through the source code, I see that [the ProfileService for TestUsers](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/b348614ea00556d85b63b844cea4a777bb4a0548/src/IdentityServer4/src/Test/TestUserProfileService.cs#L41-L62) should add all requested claims to the token via [an extension method](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/44651bea9b02c992902639b21205f433aad47d03/src/IdentityServer4/src/Extensions/ProfileDataRequestContextExtensions.cs#L33-L44). Most questions I found while googling my problem either do what I already do (or tried, see below), or are about other edge cases.

Many other threads also lead to [Dominick Baier's post on roles](https://leastprivilege.com/2016/08/21/why-does-my-authorize-attribute-not-work/), but there the problem is that the *API side* doesn't recognize the role. **My problem is that the `role` isn't included at all in the token.**

What I've tried:

- Switching between `"role"` and `JwtClaimTypes.Role` in various places.
- With and without `IdentityResources`
- Digging through the IDS4 codebase to find the logic behind this

---

**Footnote about `ProfileService`**

I've tried adding this:

```
public class ProfileService : TestUserProfileService
{
    public ProfileService(TestUserStore users, ILogger<TestUserProfileService> logger) 
        : base(users, logger)
    { }

    public override Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        var role = context.Subject.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Role);
        context.IssuedClaims.Add(role);
        return base.GetProfileDataAsync(context);
    }

    public override Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        return base.IsActiveAsync(context);
    }
}
```

to the `AddIdentityServer()` builder chain:

```
.AddProfileService<ProfileService>()
```

but the `GetProfileDataAsync(...)` method isn't being hit at all, no breakpoint triggers. So that would suggest that the default `TestUserProfileService` would also never be hit, thus explaining the lack of claims in my tokens.

Is this not supported in Password Flow perhaps because it's an OAuth2 and not an OpenID Connect flow?

---

What am I missing? Do I *really* need to [create a custom `ProfileService`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53631096/419956) to add all these claims? I really felt [the default `ProfileService` for `TestUser`s](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4/src/Test/TestUserProfileService.cs) should do this already??

Comment: there used to be a setting in the `Client` around `AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken ` or something like that... without it you wouldn't get the claims inside the token by default so would need to call now the `/userinfo` endpoint in the identity server 4 to get that data

Comment: Hmm, I think I've tried that and may do so again to double check it didn't fix things. The setting does talk about _IdToken_ though, and I want the claim to be in the access token. - Somehow my real application that uses EF Core and ASP.NET Identity _does_ "magically" include roles, so maybe I should check their source code...

Comment: I might have some start of a solution, but will hold off posting because questions without _any_ answers get way more attention, and I'd love to see someone else's insight...

Comment: For resource owner flow, you could hook into the token claims through `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` interface

Comment: Any updates on this??

Comment: @CeylanMumunKocabaş I found a way to get what I needed, not sure if it was a solution or a workaround. I've shared it as an answer.

Comment: @jeroen thank you for the response. I'm kinda will wrote my own question - it seems that my issue is a bit different.

Comment: @Jeroen i have posted a question about my issue - i don't mind if you can take a look
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63016021/role-claim-is-missing-from-the-issued-idsrv-cookie-net-core-3-1-is4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with the following (not sure if it's a solution or a workaround), for what it's worth to future visitors:

```
new ApiResource("foo-api")
{
    Scopes =
    {
        new Scope("foo-api.with.roles", new[] { "role" }),
    }
}
```

```
new Client
{
    // Don't use RPO if you can prevent it. We use it here
    // because it's the easiest way to demo with users.
    ClientId = "legacy-rpo",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = false,
    RequireClientSecret = false,
    AllowedScopes = { "foo-api", "foo-api.with.roles" },
}
```

```
new TestUser
{
    SubjectId = "EFG-456",
    Username = "mary",
    Password = "secret",
    Claims = { new Claim("role", "editor") },
}
```

And then retrieving tokens like this:

```
const response = await fetch("/connect/token", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: new URLSearchParams({
        "grant_type": "password",
        "client_id": "legacy-rpo",
        "username": "mary",
        "password": "secret",
    }),
});

const json = await response.json();

console.log(json);
```

You should be able to [clone my `sample-asp-net-core-auth-policies` repository](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-asp-net-core-auth-policies) and run it out of the box to see this at work.