# "Role" Claim is missing from the token - NET CORE 3.1 & IS4

Tags: c#, cookies, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a service which is responsible for authenticating users.

After updating:

- IdentityServer4 from 2.3.2 to 4.0.2;

an issue popped up:

- The token does not contain the required user claims anymore.

The service is configured this way:

- The Startup.cs contains:

```
applicationBuilder.UseCookiePolicy();
applicationBuilder.UseIdentityServer();
applicationBuilder.UseAuthorization();
//...
mvcCoreBuilder.AddAuthorization(ConfigureAuthorization);
var auth = mvcCoreBuilder.Services.AddAuthentication(ConfigureAuthenticationOptions);
auth.AddIdentityServerAuthentication(ConfigureIdentityServerAuthentication);
//...
void ConfigureAuthenticationOptions(AuthenticationOptions authenticationOptions)
{
    authenticationOptions.DefaultScheme = IdentityServerConstants.DefaultCookieAuthenticationScheme;
}
//...
void ConfigureAuthorization(AuthorizationOptions authorizationOptions)
{
    var requirements = new List<IAuthorizationRequirement> { new DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement() };
    var schemes = new List<string> { IdentityServerConstants.DefaultCookieAuthenticationScheme };
    authorizationOptions.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicy(requirements, schemes);
}
```

- And the (Updated for IS4 4.0.2) Login controller which sets the cookie contains:

```
props = new _AuthenticationProperties
{
    IsPersistent = true,
    ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(AccountOptions.RememberMeLoginDuration),
};

// user.Claims contains the "role" claim

var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(user.Claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, user.SubjectId));
var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

// The created claimsPrincipal contains the "role" claim

await HttpContext.SignInAsync(claimsPrincipal, props);
```

- Before updating the IS4 the controller looked like this:

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(user.SubjectId, props, user.Claims.ToArray());
```

In the api project which is being protected:

- When trying to validate for controller requests i have (in a different api project):

```
// attribute for validating roles on controllers
[AuthorizeRoles(Role.SimpleRole)] // which implements IAuthorizationFilter

// And the implementation:
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    var user = context.HttpContext.User;
    // user is of type 'ClaimsIdentity'
    // and it does not contain the "role" claim
 
    // some checks to verify the user here...
}
```

The startup of the protected api project contains:

```
builder.AddAuthorization(ConfigureAuthorization);

var auth = builder.Services.AddAuthentication(ConfigureAuthenticationOptions);

auth.AddIdentityServerAuthentication(ConfigureIdentityServerAuthentication);
```

The `ConfigureIdentityServerAuthentication` method sets some `IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions`. The `RoleClaimType` is not being set because it have a default value `'role'` which is the expected one.

The `IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions` is from the 'IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation' package version 3.0.1.

Here are two screenshots to prove that the `RoleClaimType` is set:

- on the authorization service on Startup.cs:
  [image: startup.cs]
- on the OnAuthorization method from the `AuthorizeRoles` attribute:
  [image: OnAuthorization]

The Questions:

- Why the token does not contain all of the claims which are added to the ClaimsIdentity object?
- How can this be fixed in order for the token to contain the "role" claim again?

Involved Technologies:

- Net Core 3.1
- IdentityServer4 4.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default IdentityServer and ASP.NET core have different opinion on what the name of the RoleClaim should be.

Add this code in your client to fix that mapping (setting the TokenValidationParameters option)

```
       services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/User/Login";
            options.LogoutPath = "/User/Logout";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/User/AccessDenied";
        }).AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:6001";
            options.ClientId = "authcodeflowclient";
            options.ClientSecret = "mysecret";
            options.ResponseType = "code";

            options.Scope.Clear();
            options.Scope.Add("openid");
            options.Scope.Add("profile");
            options.Scope.Add("email");
            options.Scope.Add("employee_info");


            //Map the custom claims that should be included
            options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("employment_start", "employment_start");
            options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("seniority", "seniority");
            options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("contractor", "contractor");
            options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("employee", "employee");
            options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("management", "management");
            options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey(JwtClaimTypes.Role, JwtClaimTypes.Role);

            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "/";
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;



            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
                RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,

            };

            options.Prompt = "consent";
        });
```

Also, it can be helpful to look at the various requests in Fiddler to figure out your claim issues.

Settings this one to True can also help out:

```
options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
```

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail
about this topic: [Debugging OpenID Connect claim problems in ASP.NET Core](https://To%20complement%20this%20answer,%20I%20wrote%20a%20blog%20post%20that%20goes%20into%20more%20detail%20%20about%20this%20topic:%20Debugging%20OpenID%20Connect%20claim%20problems%20in%20ASP.NET%20Core)

Comment: Can you please advise on - which class instance is the mentioned 'options' object? As i am not able to find the 'TokenValidationParameters' property in neither of the following classes: 'AuthenticationOptions', 'AuthorizationOptions', 'IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions'.

Comment: It seems that on the 'IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions' there is a property RoleClaimType - which internally is setting the TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType - i have tried but it did not made any difference - the claims are still missing.

Comment: And also the RoleClaimType and NameClaimType on the 'IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions' have default values - which are the ones from JwtClaimTypes.

Comment: I added to the answer where the TokenValidationParameters is set.

Comment: As you can see the configuration from the code samples above in the question are using IdentityServer isntead of OpenId. And i mentioned that the RoleClaimType value is already set.

Comment: Its probably a client side issue where you need to properly map the received in the AddOpenIdConnect method. I would initially use Fiddler to investigate the traffic between the client and IdentityServer to make sure the client do receive the desired claims. After you know you DO receive the desired claims, then you have a few options to map them to Roles for example and exactly which claims should be added and which claims that should be removed. Also, when you do upgrade to v4.0x you also need to make sure you add ApiScopes. will update the answer. (Added MapUniqueJsonKey)

Comment: Well it seems that i have been wrong about how the these stuff actually work - i will update my question when i have the chance...

Comment: Well, i will accept your answer, but in my particular case, i was asking kind-of-nonsenses... it was not clear enough for me what was going on. It turned out that the 'role' claim was missing from the token because it was not set in the `ApiResource.Claims` which is meant to be obtained with the help of `.AddResourceStore<ResourceStore>()` (in my case the api resources are fetched from a db). Can you please, if it is clear what i am trying to explain, add this to your answer too - and i will accept the answer.